# Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.datastax.driver.core.TypeCodec.getJavaType()Lcom/google/common/reflect/TypeToken;

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver, spark-cassandra-connector, spring-data-cassandra

I am creating an application using following dependencies, which are all the latest version so far.

```
     <parent>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
       <version>2.0.0.M5</version>
     </parent>
    `<dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5</</version>
     </dependency> 
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
     </dependency>`
```

I get this exception

```
"Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.datastax.driver.core.TypeCodec.getJavaType()Lcom/google/common/reflect/TypeToken;"
```

After doing some research, I found the reason is that `spark-cassandra-connector_2.10` jar also contains `com.datastax.driver` class files and it also has `TypeCodeC.class` but this is different from `TypeCodeC.class` file in `cassandra-driver-core`

I have 2 solutions so far.

1. use `maven-shade-plugin` to exclude class files from the jar. However, this requires a lot of extra work. And for some reason, only I compile the project to a jar and add this jar as a dependency in my project, then it works. I don't think this is a good solution
2. I remove `/com/datastax/driver` folder and files directly from the jar. Use this command

   ```
   zip -d /Users/cicidi/.m2/repository/com/datastax/spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.10/2.0.5/spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-2.0.5.jar /com/datastax/driver/*
   ```

And it works! Then you need to can add this jar to your project, instead of using maven.(you can use maven on your local, but won't work if you pull the jar from again. )

I don't find any answer on the internet. I know there will be some smart guys fixed this issue. But before that, I am posting this answer to help whoever want to fix this problem immediately.

Comment: Please edit to only ask a question. Then you can post your own answer, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer. Don't put "(solved)" in the tittle.

Answer (score 0):

```
     <dependency>
       <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
       <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
       <version>2.0.0-M1</version>
     </dependency>
```

has no version conflict with

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the question "Why is the Cassandra Java Driver embedded in Spark Cassandra Connector artifacts?" in https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/FAQ.md . It's difficult to use these two libraries together. But I try to avoid the problem by explicitly specify the dependencies in my pom.

There are some points to pay attention to: 
The cassandra-driver-* must be put before the spark-cassandra-connector. And the 3.1.4 may only work fine with 2.0.0-M1.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-extras</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-M1</version>
</dependency>
```